# Good training and validation accuracy but poor confusion matrix

Tags: matrix, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, training-data

I have training my model to detect normal vs pneumonia chest x-ray classes. This is my dataset as listed below:

```
train_batch= ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input)\
.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['NORMAL', 'PNEUMONIA'], 
batch_size=32,class_mode='categorical')
val_batch= ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
.flow_from_directory(directory=val_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['NORMAL', 'PNEUMONIA'], batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
test_batch= ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
.flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['NORMAL', 'PNEUMONIA'], batch_size=16,class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

Found 3616 images belonging to 2 classes.  #training

Found 1616 images belonging to 2 classes.  #validation

Found 624 images belonging to 2 classes.   #test
```

my model consist of 5 CNN layers where image w,h = (224* 224,3) with 16 feature map as first layer and then 32, 64, 128,256. Batch normalization , max pooling and dropout is added to every cnn layer, but last dense layer is as follow

```
model.add(Dense(units=2 , activation='softmax'))

optim = Adam( lr=0.001 )
model.compile(optimizer=optim , loss= 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics= ['accuracy'])

history=model.fit_generator(train_batch,
                  steps_per_epoch= 113,   #3616/32=113

                  epochs = 25,
                  validation_data = val_batch,
                  validation_steps = 51   #1616/32=51
                  #verbose=2
                  #callbacks=callbacks #remove to chk
```

)

as it can be seen in the graph that my training and validation accuracy and loss is good but when I plot confusion matrix it dose not seems good why??

```
prediction = model.predict_generator(test_batch,steps= stepss) #, verbose=0)

prediction1 = np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)
cm = confusion_matrix (test_batch.classes, prediction1)
print(cm)
```

this is my confusion matrix as below
[image]

as you can see my graph which is as below

[image]

after that I did fine tuning of my model with VGG!6 by replacing last dense layer with my own dense layer with two outputs and here is the graph and confusion matrix:

[image]
[image]

I do not understand why my testing in not going good even with vgg16 model as you can see the results so please give me your valuable suggestions THANKS

Comment: did you use the same amount of "normal" pictures as "pneumonia" pictures?

Comment: not like in my dataset pneumonia folder has more images then normal folder, but I have also transformed data into 70% training and 30 validation using Image data generator by using validation split but same results

Comment: so are in your train set exactly 50% pneumonia and 50% normal and in your validation set also 50% pneumonia and 50% normal?

Comment: yes but still I am not getting good test results

Comment: did you shuffle the data?

Comment: I did not shuffle the test data